# Ubuntu Install Stuck at Synchronizing SCSI Cache

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, windows-10, scsi

I am trying to switch from Windows 10 to Linux. On the PC I'm writing (ASUS Q405U) this post with, it worked fine, but on my main PC (Lenovo Legion Y7000P), the step in my install where it asks me to choose a network doesn't display any real networks, only something like "Realtek Semiconductor ...", which is a driver, not a WiFi network. I can then either choose this or choose to skip the internet connection for now. Either one gives the same problem. Eventually I get to the step where I am asked to restart to finish the install. It runs a bunch of processes just fine, then stops after

```
[ 451.475871] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
```

At this point it just waits. I've tried it many times, once letting it attempt this one step for over half an hour. I can type any text I want, and the cursor is blinking, so it's not frozen, but it won't finish this process.

Edit: I found an Ethernet cable lying around and moved my whole setup closer to the modem so I could connect to the internet. It changed the way the install ran before restart, but after restart it still sticks at `Synchronizing SCSI cache`.